# All draw Round Robin

Tags: draw

Do you know a chess tournament (I wrote Round Robin, since it seems extremely improbable for Swiss) where all games ended drawn? Since of course even I can come up from personal experience with a four player tournament where this happened, let's assume at least 8 players. Calculating with a fairly valid drawing probability of 1/2, I get 1/2^(8*7/2)~10^-9, so this would be a very rare event.

Comment: Those four guys must be pretty fun to play with...

Comment: The record for draw percentage is 93.3 (that tournament had ten players), meaning no: there hasn't been a recorded tournament with 100% draws. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_world_records_in_chess#Highest_percentage_of_draws_in_a_tournament

Comment: If that happens it's decided on penalty kicks.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson: Can you upgrade that to an answer? I didn't know that there was a chess record page on Wiki!! BTW, that result has p=10^-24...(Note that the page probably only records from some certain ELO level upwards, so I won't exclude it has happened at the Hicksville town championship...)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann with a draw probability of 50%, I calculate drawing 42 of 45 games has p~=10^-10. `C(45,42) * 0.5^42 * (1 - 0.5)^(45-42) = 4.033e-10` . (For "42 or more") the odds go up slightly: 4.328e-10)

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson: Ah, wrong bracketing on the Google calculator :-) You are correct. Next time I use MATHEMATICA...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia page of chess world records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_world_records_in_chess#Highest_percentage_of_draws_in_a_tournament), the record for draw percentage is 93.3 (that tournament had ten players), meaning no: there hasn't been a recorded tournament with 100% draws.